# Link error on some (not all) functions

Tags: c++

I am using the OpenNN2.0, and am facing an issue with referencing the .lib

If I use

```
OpenNN::DataSet data_set;
data_set.set(1, 1, 1);
```

I get a linker error:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl OpenNN::DataSet::set(unsigned int const &,unsigned int const &,unsigned int const &)" (?set@DataSet@OpenNN@@QEAAXAEBI00@Z)
5>..\x64\Release\MachineLearning.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

If I use:

```
OpenNN::DataSet data_set;
data_set.set( );
```

the linking stage works fine. I am at a complete loss as to where to look for the issue. How can I narrow down where this might come from?

Edit:
Set declarations from the header:

```
// Set methods

void set(void);
void set(const Matrix<double>&);
void set(const size_t&, const size_t&);
void set(const size_t&, const size_t&, const size_t&);
void set(const DataSet&);
void set(const tinyxml2::XMLDocument&);
void set(const std::string&);
```

Implementation from the cpp:

```
void DataSet::set(void)
{ 
    data_file_name = "";
    data.set();

    // Variables
    variables.set();

    // Instances
    instances.set();

    display = true;
}

void DataSet::set(const size_t& new_inputs_number, const size_t& new_targets_number, const size_t& new_instances_number)
{   
    data_file_name = "";
    const size_t new_variables_number = new_inputs_number + new_targets_number;  
    data.set(new_instances_number, new_variables_number);

    // Variables
    variables.set(new_inputs_number, new_targets_number);

    // Instances
    instances.set(new_instances_number);

    display = true;
}
```

Edit 2: I have output the dumpbin /ALL from the library to textfile, and compared it to the linker output. In the dumpbin file, I see a `set@DataSet@OpenNN@@QEAAXAEB_K00@Z`, which seems to be what the linker is looking for. So from I read there, the linked function really should be in the lib

Comment: How is `OpenNN::DataSet::set` declared?

Comment: One possibility could be that the no-argument `set` function is an inline function, while the three-argument one is not.

Comment: Its not inline, checked that. At some point both functions would go to a template matrix(void) or matrix(x, y) which resizes the matrix accordingly. Code there looks okay imo

Comment: I tried the 32bit version, that one compiles just fine. For some reason, the 64bit version screws up, but only difference is the target CPU type, nothing else.